# Passing a parameter into a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I need to pass this to a pivot table.

```
def weekly_totals (column):
    return round(column / 3 * 100).astype(str) + "%"


df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Name", "Date"])
print(weekly_totals(df2.groupby(["Name","Week"]
            ).agg(
                   {
                       'Date':'count'
                    }
)
)
)
```

It produces the following output simply showing the attendance in percentage.

```
Date
Name           Week        
James          2     100.0%
               3      33.0%
               4     100.0%
               5      67.0%
```

but below is my code for the pivot table but it's not working.

```
weekly_table = pd.pivot_table(weekly_totals(column), columns='Week',  values=['Date'],
                              index=['Name'],
                              fill_value=0, dropna=True)
weekly_table.plot(kind='bar')
```

I get this error `NameError: name 'column' is not defined`
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `columns` is indeed not defined. What you most probably want is save the result of `weekly_totals` that you are printing into a temporary variable, print it, and use it as an argument for `pivot_table`

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich I have done as you've said but I am getting an error saying: pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Please post the dataset; otherwise it is hard to figure out what are you trying to do.